# Do semaphores get deleted ( or deallocated ) when the system is rebooted?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, semaphore

I saved first 2 codes ( process1 and process2 ) given here -- 
http://www.anirudhtom.com/2011/02/system-v-semaphores-for-babies.html
to see what happens after running them. Output came okay but at the end of the output,

instead of this:

```
Semaphore removed from the System = Success
```

shows this:

```
Semaphore removed from the System = Permission Denied
```

I understand the semaphore is not deleted for some reason. Question is when I restart the pc is the semaphore still there using the given key id ( in this case 12345 ) ? Or is it deleted ?

Comment: Not sure it's a question for SO. But you should specify your operating system, semaphore is a general concept handled quite differently according OS...

Comment: I've added it to tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - You get a clean slate. Try it